# Export Content from Drupal to WordPress

Tags: importing-exporting

We're not Drupal developers and need to move the content from a Drupal site to a WordPress site.

We've already tried a plugin to help with this but it only imports a limited amount of content.

We then investigated it a little further and managed to find the Views module to export the content.

It is possible to duplicate Views which we will then rename Export To WordPress but it is not possible to convert those Views from the existing Table Format to RSS which we need to be able to import back into WordPress.

If there is a better way to do this, we would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually used the Views Data Export (https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export) module and created a CSV View which I could export and then used WP All Import to import all the posts into WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try the [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) module (disclosure: I'm a co-maintainer of it) to create a "report" that includes the data that you're interested in. As part of the report design, indicate which export formats you want to allow for exporting the data included in it. Typical export formats that are supported are CSV, XML, HTML, XLS, etc.

Have a look at the [Simple Table of States](http://drupal.placeto.be/reports/sample.states) example, and think of it as the equivalent of your "content to be exported". And note the hyperlinks in the upper right, which are:

- [CSV](http://drupal.placeto.be/reports/sample.states.csv).
- [XLS](http://drupal.placeto.be/reports/sample.states.xls).
- [HTML](http://drupal.placeto.be/reports/sample.states.html).
- [XML](http://drupal.placeto.be/reports/sample.states.xml).

Try any of these links to get the equivalent of the extracted information, but in the format you requested (there or other supported formats such as PDF, DOC, JSON, etc).

Checkout Forena's [Community Documentation](https://drupal.org/node/2041363) for (way) more details, and/or the [documentation that comes with the module](http://drupal.placeto.be/reports/help).